# Apps script to format selected text on a Google Slide

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-slides

I'm trying to create a script to format selected text (selected by the user using a mouse) on a Google Slide. For example, the script might change the selected text to Arial Font, size 11, left aligned.

I know how to create a new menu item to run the script within slides - so I've got that part of the puzzle.

I've tried converting a similar script created for Google Sheets ... but it doesn't seem to work with slides.

This is what I have so far:

```
function onOpen() {
let ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Macros').addItem('ParagraphFormat', 
'ParagraphFormat').addToUi();  
};

function ParagraphFormat() {
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
slide.getSelection()
.setFontSize(11)
.setFontFamily('Arial');
};
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `format selected text`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? In your situation, you select a text box? Or you select a part of the text in a text box? Or other situations? And, about `I've tried converting a similar script created for Google Sheets ... but it doesn't seem to work with slides.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike ... thanks for your reply. In my situation, I select part of the text in a text box. This is what I have so far: function ParagraphFormat() {
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
slide.getSelection()
.setFontSize(11)
.setFontFamily('Arial');
};

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the text style of the selected text in the text box of Google Slides.

`getSelection()` returns Class Selection. In this case, there are no methods of `setFontSize` and `setFontFamily`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. When you want to use `setFontSize` and `setFontFamily` to the selected text, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
slide.getSelection()
.setFontSize(11)
.setFontFamily('Arial');
```

#### To:

```
var textRange = slide.getSelection().getTextRange();
if (textRange) {
  textRange.getTextStyle().setFontSize(11).setFontFamily('Arial');
}
```

- When you use this modification, please select a text in the text box and run the script. By this, `setFontSize` and `setFontFamily` are reflected in the selected text.

#### References:

- [Class Selection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection)
- [getTextRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection#gettextrange)

### Added:

About your new question of `One more cheeky question: how would I add one more property to align the text to the left? (eg. adding .setTextAlignment('left') ... but this doesn't work)`, in the current stage, only a part of the text the text in the text box cannot be aligned. So, in this case, the paragraph of the selected text can be aligned. If you want to do this, how about the following sample script?

```js
var textRange = slide.getSelection().getTextRange();
if (textRange) {
  textRange.getTextStyle().setFontSize(11).setFontFamily('Arial');
  textRange.getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.START);
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant!! That works. Many thanks for your help Tanaike!

Comment: One more cheeky question: how would I add one more property to align the text to the left? (eg. adding .setTextAlignment('left')    ... but this doesn't work)   Thanks!

Comment: @Martin Bone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `One more cheeky question: how would I add one more property to align the text to the left? (eg. adding .setTextAlignment('left') ... but this doesn't work) Thanks!`, by guessing the expected result of your new question, I added one more sample script to my answer. Could you please confirm it? If my guess of your new question was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Absolutely amazing!! That works - brilliant. Thanks so much for your help Tanaike!!!

Comment: @Martin Bone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.